# GridLayout Items not aligning correctly

Tags: android, xml

I have 3 items:

An image View, a TextView and a CheckBox

I want the Image View(the infor icon) to appear on the far left side of a GridLayout, the text to appear at the center of the screen and the check box to appear on the far right side, despite setting up my columns correctly the images are still stacking ontop of eachother as seen in the picture; any ideas?

[image]

**custome_row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/customRow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
    android:useDefaultMargins="true"
    android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
    android:rowCount="2"
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/rowImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_info_outline" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rowTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/completedCheck"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_row="0"/>

</GridLayout>
```

Comment: Could you use LinearLayout for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I see two problems with your code

1. Your column numbers for the last two items are same, that's why It is stacking up.
2. You are not supplying the proper `layout_gravity` to each of the view.

Here is the modified code that you works

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/customRow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
    android:useDefaultMargins="true"
    android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
    android:rowCount="2"
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/rowImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:src=""
        tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars"
        android:layout_gravity="start|center_vertical"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rowTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#008269"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:text="Testing"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
       />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/completedCheck"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
        />

</GridLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your code : You have taken same code of both `CheckBox` & `TextView` :

```
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_column="2"
```

You can also take the layout gravity for this :

[image]

**Use below code :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/customRow"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
android:useDefaultMargins="true"
android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
android:rowCount="2"
android:columnCount="3"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/rowImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:id="@+id/rowTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

<CheckBox
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:text="android"
    android:id="@+id/completedCheck"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="2"
    android:layout_row="0"/>
```